# Boundaries in Classes

Tags: c#, class, variables

This may be a silly question but when I create a class how am I supposed to set properly the boundaries of the properties in it.

Example: If I have this class

```
class Product
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private int quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to limit the Quantity to 0 or higher

EDIT: Thanks for the quick response but what is the difference between the two answers. What I see is that they both do the same thing but which way is better to be used?

EDIT: How can I set up two boundaries for example - if I want quantity to be between 0 and 120?

Comment: Code Contracts is one way: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

Comment: @hatchet thanks for the suggested tools but I personally prefer to know how things work and do them the hard way. It seems more logical to me and it will be better for me write those things down and know how they work, still thanks for the response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private int quantity;
public int Quantity
{
    get { return quantity; }
    set { if (value < 0 || value>120) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); 
           else quantity = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I have one more question. How can I set up an upper boundary like if I want Quantity to be between 0 and 120

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [uint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) which has a non-negative range.

```
    private uint quantity;
    public uint Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }
```

Beware this is not CLS compliant.  So if you are designing an API or otherwise expecting cross language functionality, then the you should prefer `int` and use one of the existing answers.